# Upgrade Rails 6.1 > 7.0, add turbo-rails and importmap, gems do not install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps, turbo-rails, rails-sprockets, jsbundling-rails

I'm trying to upgrade a working legacy app to Rails 7, from Rails 6.1. I want to use Hotwire, so I added gem `turbo-rails`.

- Ruby 3.1.2
- zeitwerk
- no webpacker
- sprockets-rails
- no modern JS yet
- app passes tests
- server boots locally

Added `gem "turbo-rails"`, it bundles ok, and I booted the app. Cannot run `rails turbo:install`. Error is `Don't know how to build task 'turbo:install'`. That rake install task is not that important, but if i try to add `<%= turbo_include_tags %>` manually, i get `undefined method`. In `rails console`, the class `Turbo` is undefined.

Turbo needs something like `importmap-rails` if not using jsbundling or any other JS build tool, as suggested in the [edge guides docs for version 7.1](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-import-maps-as-javascript-asset-pipeline). (The [guides for version 7.0](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) do not mention `importmap`, they are outdated — they talk about `turbolinks`, which is not even in Rails 7.)

Added `importmap-rails`, bundles OK, and I tried to run `rails importmap:install`. The first time, the task did execute. It adds `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` to the head, but when i boot the app, i get `method undefined` for that helper.

Then i remove and re-add the `importmap-rails` gem, it bundles OK, but the `importmap:install` task is not even available. In `rails console`, the class `Importmap` is undefined. Are these gems not getting installed properly? There are no error messages from bundle, and `bundle doctor` says `No issues found`. `bundle info` shows them installed.

**How can I debug a gem that bundles, but its methods are unavailable?**

My gemfile is like this, because we don't want to load ActiveStorage and a couple other gems in core Rails.

```rb
# gem("rails", "~> 7.0")

group :rails do
  gem("actioncable")
  # gem("actionmailbox")
  gem("actionmailer")
  gem("actionpack")
  # gem("actiontext")
  gem("actionview")
  gem("activejob")
  gem("activemodel")
  gem("activerecord")
  # gem("activestorage")
  gem("activesupport")
  gem("bundler")
  gem("importmap-rails")
  gem("railties")
  gem("sprockets-rails")
  gem("turbo-rails")
end
```

I assume I need to add `gem turbo-rails` here because i'm not just using `gem rails`, and it is not a listed dependency of any of the core component gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `bundle install` all gems listed in your *Gemfile* are installed - aka downloaded. To use them you have to `require` files you need.

```rb
# config/application.rb

require_relative "boot"

# NOTE: this takes care of rails gems
#       but you probably have individual requires here
require "rails/all"

# NOTE: nothing else in `group :rails` is required
#       Rails.groups #=> [:default, Rails.env]
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

Move gems outside of the group:

```rb
group :rails do
  gem("actioncable")
  # gem("actionmailbox")
  gem("actionmailer")
  gem("actionpack")
  # gem("actiontext")
  gem("actionview")
  gem("activejob")
  gem("activemodel")
  gem("activerecord")
  # gem("activestorage")
  gem("activesupport")
  gem("bundler")
  gem("railties")
end

# now you have your gems installed and required
gem("sprockets-rails")
gem("importmap-rails")
gem("turbo-rails")
```

*https://bundler.io/guides/groups.html*

Comment: Great Scott! I never knew that. Thank you!!!