# Rails 6.1 — add `importmap-rails`, gem bundles but methods unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1, import-maps

Ruby: 3.1.2, Rails 6.1

Trying to add gem `importmap-rails` to an existing Rails 6.1 app.

The gem bundles, but neither the rake `importmap:install` task nor the gem helper method `<%= javascript_import_tags %>` are available.

In rails console, the class `Importmap` is undefined.

It seems the gem does not install properly or completely. No useful error messages raised.

How can I debug a gem that bundles but is not available? The situation doesn't make sense to me.

([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77019098/installing-turbo-rails-and-importmap-while-upgrading-rails-6-1-7-0) from earlier attempt)

Comment: Solved — the issue was that the gem was inside a `group` in the gemfile.  Linked question has the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `importmap-rails` gem was inside `group :rails` in the Gemfile, and so the class did not get required.

This does not work (linked question above has the explanation):

```rb
# gem("rails", "~> 7.0")

group :rails do
  gem("actioncable")
  # gem("actionmailbox")
  gem("actionmailer")
  gem("actionpack")
  # gem("actiontext")
  gem("actionview")
  gem("activejob")
  gem("activemodel")
  gem("activerecord")
  # gem("activestorage")
  gem("activesupport")
  gem("bundler")
  gem("importmap-rails")
  gem("railties")
  gem("sprockets-rails")
  gem("turbo-rails")
end
```

Needs to be:

```rb
group :rails do
  ...
  gem("bundler")
  gem("railties")
end

gem("importmap-rails")
gem("sprockets-rails")
gem("turbo-rails")
```